# grails domain without saving it

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, dns, grails-orm

I have :

```
def userList = [];
if(!User.findAllByGrade(10)){
   userList.add(new User());
}else{ ..... } 


<g:each in="${userList}" var="user"> 
<!-- my big form -->
</g:each>
```

I need to display a form whether the user exists or not ... so I just add "dummy" user to the list. But it will produce errors:

> Message: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: User
>   Caused by: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: User

I could use  to copy the forms, but I just wonder how to solve this ...

Comment: @nightinagle2k1: excuse me, if the user does not exist, how can you take the information in g:each? Or you don't need that information?

Comment: Is that the exact code? You would normally get that error if you attach the new User instance to a domain object that is already in the Hibernate session. The above code doesn't seem to be doing that.

Is it the `if` or the `else` that's failing?

Comment: Rendering transient objects in a form works fine for me. Looks like you're referencing the user in some other object that you're trying to save or Grails tries to flush.

What operation gives the error, exactly? Where exactly in the code the is the error? if it's save action, can you show its code?

Comment: @nightingale2k1, did you ever figure out why grails was trying to do a save in this scenario?  I think I'm running into a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the [if-else](http://www.grails.org/GSP+Tag+-+else) taglib:

```
<g:if test="${userList}">
     <!-- Your form for no-user case here. -->
</g:if>
<g:else>
     <!-- Your form for g:each case here. -->
</g:else>
```

Comment: It's an unnecessary code duplication, one would need at least to move the form code into separate template. Additionally, I don't see a reason not to make it work as proposed.

Comment: @Victor: I don't think that it will duplicate, since it seems that in no-user case, it doesn't need the user information at all. Waiting for confirmation, though.

Comment: It will only differ in field values rendered, right? Rendering an empty domain object would do the same, plus will render default User field values; if defaults change, we won't have to change GSP.

Answer (score 0):

A bit dirty, but it should work:

```
def userList = [];
if(!User.findAllByGrade(10)){
   userList.add([:]);
}else{ ..... }
```

So instead of creating a new User instance, just add an empty hashtable to the list; if the result doesn't look ok, you need to do a bit more work:

```
def userList = [];
if(!User.findAllByGrade(10)){
   userList.add([name:"", age:"", foobar:""]);
}else{ ..... }
```

I.e. create entries in the hashtable that correspond to the attributes of `User`.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `null` to the list instead of `new User()` and then, in gsp, referring to user's properties using safe navigation operator `.?` (like `user?.name` so NPE wouldn't be thrown)

So the code will be more like:

```
def userList = [];
if(!User.findAllByGrade(10)){
   userList. << null
}else{ ..... } 


<g:each in="${userList}" var="user"> 
<!-- my big form -->
    <g:textField name="name" value="${user?.name}" />
</g:each>
```